# time magic IPython inconsistent with documentation

Tags: ipython

Based on documentation of time function

> the actual exponentiation is done by Python
> at compilation time, so while the expression can take a noticeable
> amount of time to compute, that time is purely due to the
> compilation.the time needed by Python to compile the given expression will be
> reported if it is more than 0.1s.

and as an example

```
  In [1]: %time 2**128
  CPU times: user 0.00 s, sys: 0.00 s, total: 0.00 s
  Wall time: 0.00
```

However when I run the same line of code I get

```
CPU times: user 7 µs, sys: 0 ns, total: 7 µs
Wall time: 9.06 µs
```

Comment: Are you bothered by the different time numbers?  One is in `ns` and the other `s`.  The `ns` rounded to `s` are the same, `0.00`.  I haven't seen that full doc page, but I think you should take that example as illustrative, not exact.  Actual times will vary with computer.  Your times will vary each time you call it.  For what it's worth, I prefer to use `%timeit`, especially for code this small and fast.

Comment: @hpaulj I know what you're saying, but that doesn't answer my question, why is it reporting time when it's not over 0.1s?

Comment: i've never been picky enough about this.  I read the `user` part, and move on.  I prefer the repeated testing of `timeit`